# Use CSS selector to change div class at pair of 2 elements

Tags: html, css

I tried using CSS to select a collection of divs in pairs of 2 at 2.

Example:

I have AA AA AA AA AA AA but using selector need change css of 2 elements in step of 2 (A and B letter is a DIV):

AA BB AA BB AA BB

I'm trying

```
&:nth-child(3n+3)
```

But without success. Any help?

Comment: @Jorden1337 Its not exactly. See example I don't need A B A B A but A A B B A A B B A A

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correct, you need 2 rules to do that

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(4n+3),
div:nth-child(4n+4) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div><div>A</div>
<div>A</div><div>A</div>
<div>A</div><div>A</div>
<div>A</div><div>A</div>
<div>A</div><div>A</div>
<div>A</div><div>A</div>
```

Comment: Perfect I tried that but probably second selector have a (3n+x) wrong parameter thanks.